# Java Array with the same name as a class name

Tags: java

I really can't find any information about it that's why I'm asking here. 
I'm trying to figure out what is it type of Array if it has same name as a class...  like:

```
public class ArrayOne {
    int SomeInt; 
    ArrayOne [] arr; 

    public ArrayOne(SomeInt){

       arr=new ArrayOne[1];
    }

}
```

Maybe someone know where can I read about it. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's an array of that type, in your case an array of `ArrayOne`s. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare an array like this:

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[3];
```

you have an array of int (remember that int in java is not an object)

So if you write:

```
ArrayOne[] arr;
```

You will have an array of object from class ArrayOne.

If you are still in doubt, you can check an array type like this:

```
Class ofArray = o.getClass().getComponentType();
```

take a look here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--

> public Class getComponentType()
>
> Returns the Class representing the component type of an array. If this class does not represent an array class this method returns null.

Comment: How can I convert this Object`s Array to Int Array if I only need to Sort Integer Values of an Object for example with Bubble Sort? Because I can't use (ArrayOne[] arr) as a Parameter for example in Bubble Sort? Thank you again.

Comment: So this bubble sort algorithm, are you going to implement? If this is the case, you can pass the array o objects to the function. But you have to adapt the impllementation, to use something like arr.intValue . Or you can just create an array of int inside your ArrayOnr class, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

That would be an array of that classes objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your `arr` variable will be of Array type, which contains objects of `ArrayOne` type.
If the question is around naming, then your array is named `arr` but not after the class which it is typed with.